# Possible to save multiple datastore entities of multiple kinds in one transaction?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore

Is it possible to save multiple datastore entities of multiple kinds in one transaction with the node api for google datastore ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Cloud Datastore does support writing multiple kinds in the same transaction. To take an [example from the getting started guide](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial#storing_data), you could update a `Task` entity and write a new kind, in this case logging a user event:

```
function markDone (taskId) {
  const transaction = datastore.transaction();
  const taskKey = datastore.key([
    'Task',
    taskId
  ]);

  return transaction.run()
    .then(() => transaction.get(taskKey))
    .then((results) => {
      const task = results[0];
      task.done = true;
      transaction.save({
        key: taskKey,
        data: task
      },
      // Also write a log of the user action.
      {
        key: datastore.key(['User', current_user, 'Event']),
        data: [{
            name: 'event',
            value: 'TaskDone'
          }]
      }]);
      return transaction.commit();
    })
    .then(() => {
      // The transaction completed successfully.
      console.log(`Task ${taskId} updated successfully.`);
    })
    .catch(() => transaction.rollback());
}
```

Comment: awesome thanks. While on the subject of updating is there anyway to do optimistic locking so that one can be sure one is not overwriting any fields that may have been written elsewhere by another transaction that started just before this one started and committed just before this one committed?

Comment: Cloud Datastore transactions are serializable. So when your transaction reads the data, you can be guaranteed that is hasn't changed when you then commit the transaction. If it has the transaction will fail (and the transaction runner should retry). Note that this is on the Entity (actually Entity Group) level, not the field level, so additional fields from other transactions would still fail the transaction, even if your transaction isn't touching those fields.